# Every differential equation is equivalent to a first-order system. Does the converse hold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, control-theory

We know that every differential equation is equivalent to a first-order system. I am trying to prove or disprove the converse. For example in $\mathbb{R}^2$, if we have a system $\dot{x}=f(x,y)$, $\dot{y}=g(x,y)$. Can we always convert it to one differential equation (for example, only in terms of $x$)? Under what condition, this is possible?
Thank you, in advance, for your response!

Comment: A short (and trivial) answer to your first question: No, consider $$\begin{cases}\dot{x}=f(x),\\ \dot{y}=g(y).\end{cases}$$ Regarding the second question, that's a different thing.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It makes sense.

Comment: @user539887 But would it not be possible to do a coordinate transformation, such as $z=x+y$, such that $x$ and $y$ can be recovered from $z$ and $\dot{z}$?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Yes, when you write the system in the coordinates, say, $z=x+y$, $u=x-y$, then, in general, $\dot{z}$ and $\dot{u}$ depend on both $z$ and $u$, and Robert Israel's answer applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your example.  In order to make this a second-order equation in $x$, you want to solve $\dot{x} = f(x,y)$ for $y$ as a function of $x$ and $\dot{x}$, say $y = a(x, \dot{x})$.  This may or may not be possible, (and in most cases even if it is possible in principle it can't be done in closed form).  Then
we get $$ \ddot{x} = f_1(x,y) \dot{x} + f_2(x,y) \dot{y} = 
f_1(x,a(x,\dot{x})) \dot{x} + f_2(x,a(x,\dot{x})) g(x,a(x,\dot{x}))$$
where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are the partial derivatives of $f$.